# Need a list of android devices. One in each Screen category

Tags: android

I'm trying to find one phone to fit in each of the categories listed on the android site : [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/screens.html).

Reason being is that I want to order at lest one device in each category to test layouts on. I know that I could do this on the emulator fairly easy. However, my company would like to also use physical devices and we have the budget to do so :) I'm having a hard time categorizing different phones into the different categories. Is there any such list that already exists?

I started trying to manually calculate dp based on pixels and dpi listed on gmsareana.com. I'm finding that some phones don't even seem to fall in the categories listed : [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources.)
For example the LG axis (http://www.gsmarena.com/lg_axis-3731.php) after calculating the dp has the following: 438dp X 263dp. This doesn't meet the small screen size criteria (small: Screens that are of similar size to a low-density QVGA screen. The minimum layout size for a small screen is approximately 320x426 dp units. Examples are QVGA low density and VGA high density). Perhaps something is wrong w/ my dp formula? dp = (px*160)/dpi?

I think its possible that gmsareana could have bad info, but I'm still at a loss for coming up with physical devices I can order that fit into each of the major screen sizes and densities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i prepared a similar list somteime ago. check if its useful for you

Samsung Ace 3.5 in HVGA (320*480)
Samsung galaxy S 4.0 inches WVGA(480*800)
Samsung galaxy II 4.3 in WVGA(480*800)

Sony Ericsson xperia x10  4 inches FWVGA(854*480)
Sony Ericsson xperia play 4 in FWVGA(854*480)
Sony Ericsson xperia ray 3.3 in FWVGA(854*480)
Sony Ericsson xperia arc 4.2 in FWVGA(854*480)
Sony Ericsson xperia arc plus 4.2 in FWVGA(854*480)
Sony ericsson xperia pro 3.7 inches FWVGA(854*480)

LG optimus 3.2 in HVGA(320 * 480)
HTC Desire 3.7 in WVGA(480*800)
HTC wildfire 3.2 QVGA (320*240)
HTC wildfire S 3.2 HVGA (320*480)

Answer (score 2):

[Check the 'display' section of this table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Android_devices#Smartphones)

Comment: This is a great list. However, try finding a Small Screen, High Density device on that list that you can actually order. According to the metrices that represents 2.9% of the market.

Comment: Perhaps maybe your company shouldn't worry about that 2.9%?

Heres another list that may help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_displays_by_pixel_density